# Как сделать маршрутизацию без get запросов

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Есть проект, на котором используется devExtreme и так получилось, что на проекте нет Get запросов, только Post
Проблема в том, что при переходе на какую либо страницу отсутствует возможность вернуться назад по стрелке в браузере и в адресной строке есть только дефолтный контроллер, возможно ли как-то решить эту проблему без Get запросов?

Comment: что вы пытаетесь сделать? что мешает создать get запрос?

Comment: Это уже проект в продакшене, он довольно большой, переписывать все контроллеры и добавлять get запросы очень тяжело, а проблема в том, что пользователи не могут использовать кнопку "Назад" в браузере и мне интересно, можно ли как то с этим разобраться без переписывания проекта и добавления get запросов

Comment: а причем тут devextreme?

Comment: Да в целом наверное не причем =) 
Я  сейчас пытаюсь отловить через middleware на какой контроллер и экшен попадает юзер при переходе, но пока не пойму откуда вытащить данные о контроллере, а потом буду пробовать через js записывать каждый переход в history

Comment: А зачем использовать кнопку "Назад"? Да и при переходе назад в случае POST-запроса браузер предлагает заново отправить данные. Либо сделать на странице дополнительную кнопку "Назад".

Comment: На проекте очень много форм и переходов между ними, очень часто приходится возвращаться на шаг или 2 назад, дополнительная кнопка это хорошо, но хочется что бы работала и стандартная браузерная кнопка т.к. пользователи использующие данный продукт далеки от веба и ИТ в целом, они знаю про стандартную кнопку и хотят тыкать на нее